# Determining whether equation $\ln x=\frac{1}{3}x$ has at least 3 solutions

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to say whether

$$\ln x=\frac{1}{3}x$$

Has at least 2 solutions, and after that the problem asks us to tell if the third solution exists...

So I managed to find 1 solution: $f(x)=\ln x - \frac{1}{3} x$, $f(e)>0, f(1)=-\frac{1}{3} < 0$, so by the mean value theorem we have $f(y)=0$ for some $y\in [1,e]$.

What to do about the other two?

UPDATE: I haven't covered derivatives yet in my course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to $x = e^{x/3}$, and then to

$e^x = 3 x$

sketch the graph of $e^x$ and of $3 x$. Observe that:
$e^x$ is always increasing in $x$, and always curving upwards. 
$3 x$ (a straight line) is always increasing in $x$, does not curve.

So, starting from small $x$, if your straight line crosses $e^x$, then it must cross back again (because the $e^x$ keeps on curving upwards).

You cannot get more than 2 crossings because $e^x$ only curves upwards (you would need e.g. an "s" shape to get 3 crossings of a straight line).

The only other possibility would be that the 2 lines touch but do not cross, giving 1 solution.

Let's see now: 
at $x=0$, $e^x=1$, $3 x = 0$   so $e^x > 3 x$  
at $x=1$, $e^x = 2.71...$, $3 x = 3$  so $e^x < 3 x$  
and for $x \to \infty$, $e^x > 3 x$

So we get exactly 2 crossings.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find first derivative and second derivative. Analyze the signs. What do they tell you?

Comment: Thanks, but we haven't covered derivatives yet...

Comment: hmm, how about try $f(e^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lnx%3D%281%2F3%29x%20graph) of the given equation, the plot of ln(x) bends towards X-axis after the second point of intersection while the plot of $\frac13x$ continues straight above. So, there won't be a third solution of the equation.